# Biot-Savart confusion

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields

I’m tackling a question which required to work out the magnetic field at a distance from a current element. The struggle is when with the cross product in the formula. For example the current element is at zero and the point we want to calculate the magnetic field at is (0, 3 m, 4 m). I’m not sure hope we manipulate the cross product so we can do the integral to calculate the magnetic field.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven’t explained your problem with the cross product.

Comment: When I take the cross product I write it instead as   dlsin(x)  and then at this point I integrate the dl to get l. Then when I substitute all values in the formula I get the wrong answer. Just started using stack exchange so I’m not sure how to type equations sorry.

Comment: What happened to the length of the other vector? And the angle “x” isn’t going to stay constant.

Answer (score 0):

With the paucity of information in the problem, it's difficult to proceed, but assume we have a current element:

$$ d\vec I = (dI_x, dI_y, dI_z) $$

at $\vec r_0$, and we want to compute a cross product at $\vec r_1$. Of course you need:

$$ \vec R \equiv \vec r_1 - \vec r_0 = (0, 3 , 4){\rm m} $$

and we're looking to compute:

$$ d\vec B \propto \frac{d\vec I \times \vec R}{R^2} $$

...when in doubt: write out the components:

$$ dB_x \propto (dI_yR_z - dI_zR_y) = \frac 1{25}(4dI_y - 3dI_z){\, \rm m}$$
$$ dB_y \propto (dI_zR_x - dI_xR_z) = \frac 1{25}(- 4dI_z) {\, \rm m}$$
$$ dB_z \propto (dI_xR_y - dI_yR_x) = \frac 1{25}(+ 3dI_x ){\, \rm m}$$